# pandas decides to set new column type as object even though all elements are int

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very big program and the following line *sometimes* creates the "weekday" column to be `object` dtype instead of `int64` dtype

```
df.loc[:, "weekday"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).map(lambda x: x.weekday())
```

I tried dumping out the following:

```
print(f"weekday previously in columns: {'weekday' in df.columns}")  # got False
df.loc[:, "weekday"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).map(lambda x: x.weekday())
print(f"weekday type {df.dtypes['weekday']}") # got object
if df.dtypes['weekday'] != 'int64':
    for idx, weekday in zip(df.index, df['weekday']):
        # suprirsingly, this doesn't print out anything!
        if not instance(weekday, int):
            print(idx, weekday, type(weekday))
```

The fact that my `not instance` section doesn't print out anything means that all elements in `weekday` column are indeed `int`.

I also dumped the df to csv, and all weekdays are "4". There's no null or other weird values in it.

Then what could be the reason that pandas decided to set `weekday` column as `object` dtype? Or any suggested way to debug further?

Comment: I found why. My DataFrame is empty lol